# printfn written before function call prints after it

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

```
let PrintResult x = 
    printfn "%s" x

let testFP = "A" |> PrintResult

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%s" "Inside main function"
    testFP
    0
```

When the above code is executed this is the output I get:

A

Inside main function

Can I know why the output statements print in the wrong order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

testFP is not a function as you are expecting. A function must have a parameter. In F# we use the type [`unit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type) to express the absence of values, and its only value is `()`. *"A"* is printed when the statement is evaluated, and testFP is assigned the output of `"A" |> PrintResult`, which is  `()`, in other words, nothing. `printfn` outputs to the terminal as a side-effect and returns `unit`.

1. *"A"* is printed as soon as testFP is declared.
2. The main function prints *"Inside main function"*.
3. The "call" to testFP is an empty statement that does nothing, it's just the value `()`.

Simply add `()` as a parameter placeholder to fix your code:

```ml
let testFP () = "A" |> PrintResult

testFP ()
```

Comment: Just a small correction or elaboration to "In F# we use `unit` or `()` for short in place of no arguments." As far as I understand, `unit` is only a type and `()` is the only value for this type. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/unit-type